# d3.json is not executed

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm making what's supposed to be a very simple pie chart, but somehow the d3.json function is not being executed at all. My code is as below:

```
function omst1() {
"use strict";
var chartWidth = $("#chart").width()*0.5;
var chartHeight = $("#chart").height()*0.5;

var margin = {
    top: chartWidth*0.01,
    right: chartWidth*0.01,
    bottom: chartWidth*0.01,
    left: chartWidth*0.01
},
width = chartWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
height = chartHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom,
radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#F1BD98", "#DA6A26", "#82A0D3", "#094D86"])

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.outerRadius(radius - margin.bottom)
.innerRadius(radius - margin.bottom);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.sort(null)
.value(function(d) {
    return d.Aantal
}
);

var svg = d3.select("#omst1").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.json("omstandigheden.json", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(data);
  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.Omstandigheid); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.Omstandigheid; });
});

  function type(d) {
  d.Aantal = +d.Aantal;
  return d;
  }
}
```

With this setup the console.log(data) should return an object with values of *omstandigheid* and *aantal*, the JSON file is an array of objects, looking like this:

```
  {
    "Omstandigheid": "A",
    "Aantal": 2
  },
```

At first I figured my indentation was off, or perhaps I was simply closing brackets in the wrong place. Sadly I haven't found the error in my code yet, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: After Gerardo's answer I've removed the 'type' parameter and altered the code trying to use forEach instead of 'type'. The changed code is now as follows:

```
d3.json("omstandigheden.json", function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(data);
      var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

      g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.Omstandigheid); });

      g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.data.Omstandigheid; });

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Aantal = +d.Aantal;
        return d;
    })
});
}
```

Comment: Could you get a plnkr together or something ? Or show all your code you have some missing

Comment: nothing in the console? Do you get the `svg` element in your DOM with the correct width and height? Did you double-check the file name and path?

Comment: you are using: d3.json(file, type, callback). What is that type parameter doing in there? I cant seem to find such signature in D3 documentation...

Comment: @ocket-san thanks for pointing that out! I was using an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235) to guide me, but removing the 'type' parameter actually allowed me to log the data in the console. Nothing is being displayed yet though, which I'm looking into now.

Comment: Np, but you should accept Gerardo his answer ;-). I wasn't 100% sure, otherwise i would have put it into an answer myself ;-)

Comment: @ocket-san, you should have answered, you're correct! @Yoeri, that worked in Bostock's example because he used CSV, and CSV functions allow accessors. The only thing `type ` is doing here is forcing a coercion, making sure that the value is a number. You can easily do that with a `forEach`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Not as easily as I thought though, could you take a look at the edit I've made @Gerardo? It seems I don't quite get what you mean just yet.

Comment: Perfect, but the forEach must be the first thing in the callback, before the `var g`.

Comment: Oh, and you don't need that "return d".

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I still don't get an SVG element in my div, I've verified the div names in the JS, but when inspecting the div on my page there's no svg element. I'm very confused.. This hasn't happened before. Am I doing a dozen things wrong at the same time?

Comment: SIgh, mondaymornings. I've been working with a css ID when that wasn't defined yet. Everything is fine. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Good to know! But listen, if you are the one making the JSON you don't need the coercion... after all, you know the difference between a string and a number. I'll edit my answer to add this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `type` in the JSON function. JSON functions don't allow "accessors", only CSV and TSV functions allow them.

Thus, remove the `type` and do everything the `type` function does using a `forEach` inside your JSON function.

The first line of your JSON function has to be:

```
d3.json("omstandigheden.json", function(error, data) {
```

PS: If you are the one writing the JSON, you don't need the `type` function: just write the values as numbers, not strings.

Comment: Thanks for the update, always nice to get rid of rudimentary code :)